# Why is virtual operator== called on the Base class instead of the Derived class?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, equality

I defined a `virtual operator==` in my `Base` class. But for some reason, it seems it's not really treated as virtual.

See this example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>

template<class T> struct EqualByValue {
  bool operator()(T const* a, T const* b) const { return *a == *b; }
};

struct Base {
  virtual bool operator==(Base const& other) const {
    std::cerr << "Base==" << std::endl;
  }
};

struct Derived : Base {
  virtual bool operator==(Derived const& other) const {
    std::cerr << "Derived==" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  typedef boost::unordered_set<Base*, boost::hash<Base*>, EqualByValue<Base> > 
    MySet;
  MySet s;
  Derived* d1 = new Derived();
  Derived* d2 = new Derived();
  s.insert(d1);
  s.insert(d2);
  s.find(d2);
  delete d1; delete d2; return 0;
}
```

The output is `Base==` instead of the desired output `Derived==`.

Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Because your virtual method in `Derived` does *not* have the same signature of the one in `Base`.  Therefore it doesn't override it.  Derived now has two `==` method, one that takes `const Base &` and another than takes `const Derived &`.  You'll probably need *double dispatch*, but somebody else will explain all this better!

Comment: btw, your `operator==` doesn't return anything in both classes. this is UB

Comment: Actually the second `operator==` hide the first one. If you call `Base b1; d1->operator==(b1);` you will got build error, because of the first `operator==` has been hide..

Comment: @ZijingWu, I think that might not be correct.  Why do you say that?

Comment: @Frank, I guess you need to think about the big picture here.  There are four possibilities:  If a Base is being compared to a Base, then you want the Base comparator to be used.  Similarly, if two Derived objects are being compared, you want the Derived comparator to be used.  What what about `*base==*derived` and `*derived==*base`?  Perhaps you want the Base comparator used there?  (Or maybe you don't care!).  This can be fixed, but I suggest you update your question discussing these possibilities and which behaviour you desire.

Comment: @aronMcDaid, which part do you think might be incorrect? I just want to point out function hidding are happening here instead of overriding. That's why I comment it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is you're actually not overriding `operator==` because the original one has a different signature. Let's demonstrate that by using a useful C++11 feature called `override`:

```
struct Derived : Base {
  virtual bool operator==(Derived const& other) const override {
  //                                                  ^^^^^^^^
    std::cerr << "Derived==" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

[Compiling it with GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ebd6bfd838d75bf) results in the following error:

```
main.cpp:15:8: error: ‘bool Derived::operator==(const Derived&) const’ marked override, but does not override

   bool operator==(Derived const& other) const override {
```

To solve the problem, simply modify `Derive`'s `operator==` to have the same signature as `Base`'s:

```
struct Derived : Base {
  bool operator==(Base const& other) const override {
    std::cerr << "Derived==" << std::endl;
    // ...
  }
};
```

And whenever you can, use `override` so you can make the compiler detect these kinds of errors.

Answer (score 2):

(***I've added a simpler solution at the end that makes the simple assumption that equality should be false if the dynamic types of the two objects are different.***)

The `operator==` within Derived does not override the `operator==` within Base.  The have different signatures, one accepts a Base& as `other`, the other a Derived&.  They must be identical for overriding to work (you can change the return-type a little, but not the parameter types.)

One solution is to fix this with [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch).  You defined a method (or perhaps a free function) called `real_comparator` that will actually do the comparison work.  There are four versions of `real_comparator`, two each in each of the Base and Derived classes.

When we do `a==b`, we want the dynamic type of both variables to be taken into account. `a==b` is rewritten by the compiler as `a.operator==(b)` and therefore, by default, only the `a` takes part in polymorphism.  We want to change this so that both variables (and therfore, all four possibilities) can be activated.

The trick is in `return other.real_comparator(*this);`

```
struct Derived;

struct Base {
  virtual bool real_comparator(Base const& /*other*/) const {
          std::cerr << "Base == Base?" << std::endl;
          return false;
  }
  virtual bool real_comparator(Derived const& /*other*/) const {
          std::cerr << "Base == Derived?" << std::endl;
          return false;
  }

  virtual bool operator==(Base const& other) const {
    return other.real_comparator(*this);
  }
};

struct Derived : Base {
  virtual bool real_comparator(Base const& /*other*/) const override {
          std::cerr << "Derived == Base?" << std::endl;
          return false;
  }
  virtual bool real_comparator(Derived const& /*other*/) const override {
          std::cerr << "Derived == Derived?" << std::endl;
          return false;
  }

  virtual bool operator==(Base const& other) const override {
    return other.real_comparator(*this);
  }
};
```

I think this code can be simplified a little, especially if you have a rule which says "the result of the comparison shall always be false if the two objects are of different dynamic type", or something like that.

---

A simpler solution is possible, but it depends on what problem you want to solve.  Let's assume that, if two objects have different dynamic type, then the comparison should return false:

```
#include<typeinfo>  // We need this for typeid to work
using namespace std;

struct Base {
  virtual bool operator==(Base const& other) const {
          if(typeid(other) != typeid(*this))
                  return false;
          else  
                cout << "A pair of Bases" << endl;
          return true; // replace this with code to compare two Base objects
  }
};

struct Derived : Base {

  virtual bool operator==(Base const& other) const override {
          if(typeid(other) != typeid(*this))
                  return false;
          else  
                cout << "A pair of Deriveds" << endl;

          // So 'other' is actually a Derived.
          const Derived * derived_pointer = dynamic_cast<const Derived*>(&other);
          // Now, we can compare 'this' to 'derived_pointer', both pointers to Derived
          return derived_pointer == this; // replace this with code to compare two Derived
  }
};
```

This should be correct, but maybe it could be improved in some ways.  Any feedback appreciated?

Comment: Unfortunately, you now have a cyclical dependency in your code, since the `Base` class needs to know about `Derived` to provide one of the comparator overloads.

Comment: I think that can be improved, but it depends on what the rules are about comparing objects of different type.  Should they always be false?  Or should they always compare the matching-subobjects and return the corresponding result?  Such knowledge would help guide any improvements, perhaps allowing us to remove the `struct Derived` at the start.